# Seconds are being skipped in my WIndows 8 digital clock app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am developing a digital clock for windows 8 app.

And strangely some random second is being skipped in every minute. I am not sure why it is happening. One of my guesses is it might be because sometimes to retrieve that custom second image its taking more than a second and hence the next second gets skipped.

This is my code in XAML

```
<!-- second -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-15,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0"

                        Source="{Binding CurrentTime, Converter={StaticResource ThemeTimeConverterSecondDigit1}}" Opacity="0.99" Stretch="None" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1"

                        Source="{Binding CurrentTime, Converter={StaticResource ThemeTimeConverterSecondDigit2}}" Opacity="0.99" Stretch="None" Margin="-30,0,0,0" />
                </Grid>
```

The binding variable Current Time gives me the time and i use a converter to get the custom image for that time.

This is the code for my converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (!(value is DateTime))
        {
            return value;
        }


        System.DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

        var dt = (DateTime)value;

        var timePeriod = dt.ToString("tt ").StartsWith("A") ? TimePeriod.AM : TimePeriod.PM;

        if (!this.IsTwentyFourHour && dt.Hour > 12)
        {
            dt = dt.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(12));
        }

        switch (this.Component)
        {

            case ThemeComponents.SecondDigit1:
                {
                    var sec = _GetFirstDigit(dt.Second);
                    return this.CurrentTheme.SmallDigits.Where(d => d.Value == sec).First().Image;
                }
            case ThemeComponents.SecondDigit2:
                {
                    var sec = _GetSecondDigit(dt.Second);
                    return this.CurrentTheme.SmallDigits.Where(d => d.Value == sec).First().Image;
                }
}


private int _GetFirstDigit(int number)
    {
        if (number >= 10)
        {
            return System.Convert.ToInt32(number.ToString().Substring(0, 1));
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private int _GetSecondDigit(int number)
    {
        if (number >= 10)
        {
            return System.Convert.ToInt32(number.ToString().Substring(1, 1));
        }

        return System.Convert.ToInt32(number.ToString().Substring(0, 1));
    }
```

Please give me your views on why this might be happening or if u have any better ways to implement it. Thanks

EDIT:

I replaced the images with text blocks and gave just plain numbers and its still happening. The seconds are still being skipped

EDIT: 
This is the code for how the Current time is set

```
 var timeoutputShown = false;

        _ClockTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _ClockTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        _ClockTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            App.ViewModel.CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;

            if (!timeoutputShown)
            {
                timeoutputShown = true;
                //ShowTimePanelStoryboard.Begin();
            }
        };
```

Answer:

I reduced the interval from 1000ms to 100ms and that did it. Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: Try just spitting out the text of the current time, and watching that for a few minutes. If it still skips you can rule out the image loading time as being the culprit.

Comment: Ok... i replaced the images with text blocks and its still happening. The seconds are still being skipped. Now i have no idea why it can be happening....any ideas??

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've never done any Windows 8 development, so I don't have any specific recommendations. Good luck in getting it worked out.

Comment: How is CurrentTime being updated? Would you mind posting that code?

Comment: posted the code for how the current time is updated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ticking your timer at 1 second intervals, then you effectively have a margin of error of 1 second too, and therefore the dispatcher queue only needs to be held for a small amount of time in order to drop a second from being displayed. You might be better to run your timer at a higher frequency so you have less of a window for error, and do less work because you are going to be called so frequently.

For example if you run your timer to tick every 0.1secs or 100ms then you can update the seconds up to 10 times a second, and then only draw screen updates when the value to display actually changes.

So for example in a clock that only shows seconds we could do;

Public void timer_tick(...)
{
  MySeconds = DateTime.Now.Seconds:
}

Where

Public int MySeconds
{
  set 
  {
    // Only if the second has actually changed
    if (_mySeconds != value)
   {
      _mySeconds = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged(...);
    }
  }
}

The trick is to do as little as possible at each stage.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the DispatcherTimer to fire an event that updates the clock time.

```
public void startTimer()
{
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
//Fire the Tick event every second
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
timer.Tick += timer_Tick();
timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
//Do whatever you want ex, refresh the time and show it in an label
}
```

Maybe it's also better for you to create an custom font, style an label and use that combination to display the clock.

For more info about DispatcherTimer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx

Comment: You need to run the timer at a sub 1 second time since it runs approximately once a second. Even being integrated into the dispatcher queue does not prevent something else from being active at the time and causing the timer_tick to wait.

Comment: It's also possible to call DateTime.Now(); twice an second. When the queue is more than 50ms most of the times that means there's something wrong...

Comment: I have updated my question with the code for how am updating the time and its pretty similar to what you posted here......But the trick that did it was i reduced the time span to 0.1 sec as suggested by AlSki and it works perfectly now. Thanks everyone for your suggestions!